# AND operator is working but OR operator is not working in if condition on selecting radio(and/or)button using codeiniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

here, i want to execute search query for multiple fields, which based on AND & OR operator which to get action i placed two radio button one is for AND OPERATOR(match both criteria) and other is OR OPERATOR(ONE of the criteria).

my problem here AND operator is running successfully but OR operator is not working on running.

i wrote the below code:

**Model:**

```
// Variables treatise
$lnameFilter=$this->input->post('lnameFilter');
$id=$this->input->post('id');
$firstname= $this->input->post('fname');
$opt=$this->input->post('and');
$strWhere="id_photo LIKE "."'%".$id."%'";

// $lnamefilter treatise
if(!empty($lnameFilter)) {
    // AND OPERATOR (ON SELECTING RADIO BUTTON)
    if($opt==1) { 
        if($strWhere != "") {
            $strWhere=$this->db->where("($strWhere"." AND lastname LIKE "."'%".$lnameFilter."%')"); 
        } 
        else {
            $strWhere=$this->db->where("(lastname LIKE "."'%".$lnameFilter."%')"); 
        }
    }
    // OR OPERATOR (ON SELECTING RADIO BUTTON)
    if($opt==2) {
        if($strWhere != "") {
            $strWhere=$this->db->where("($strWhere"." OR lastname LIKE "."'%".$lnameFilter."%')");
        } 
        else {
            $strWhere=$this->db->where("(lastname LIKE "."'%".$lnameFilter."%')");
        }
    }
}

// $firstname treatise
if(!empty($firstname)) {
    if($opt==1) {
        if($strWhere != "") {
            $strWhere=$this->db->where("($strWhere"." AND firstname LIKE "."'%".$firstname."%')");
        }
        else {
            $strWhere=$this->db->where("(firstname LIKE "."'%".$firstname."%')");
        }
    }
    if($opt==2) {
        if($strWhere != "") {
            $strWhere=$this->db->where("($strWhere"." OR firstname LIKE "."'%".$firstname."%')");
        }
        else {
            $strWhere=$this->db->where("(firstname LIKE "."'%".$firstname."%')");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of `$strWhere`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do $strWhere = $this->db->where(); Use like instead of where

just do your conditions

```
//ands

$this->db->like('id_photo', $id);
$this->db->like('id_photo', $lastname);
//chain the likes this way instead of "(($strWhere)"." OR lastname LIKE "."'%".$lnameFilter."%')"


//ors

$this->db->like('id_photo', $id);
$this->db->or_like('id_photo', $lastname);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: $this->db->or_like('id_photo', $lastname);
to
$this->db->or_like('lastname', $lastname);

i think so...y id_photo can u explain

Comment: $this->db->where('ID', $ID);
                $this->db->or_like('LastName', $lname); 

this code worked for OR...THANQ ur code help me to think....@Parker Dell

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are doing here but try this....on the two lines where the OR is

change

```
 $strWhere=$this->db->where("($strWhere"." OR lastname LIKE "."'%".$lnameFilter."%')");
```

to

```
 $strWhere=$this->db->where("(($strWhere)"." OR lastname LIKE "."'%".$lnameFilter."%')");
```

That should solve it.
Your issue is that the `$strWhere` and the `OR` statement is executed left to right and it can get very confused if you have an `AND` and an `OR` in it.

Comment: its not working @Forbs.. still AND operator only working
$strWhere=$this->db->where("(($strWhere)"." OR lastname LIKE "."'%".$lnameFilter."%')");

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$strWhere=$this->db->where("(".$strWhere.") OR (lastname LIKE '%".$lnameFilter."%')");
```